# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста! Никак не могу определиться с обособлением этих приложений. Вроде по правилам, если приложение неоднословное, то ставится тире. Но в интернете столько встречала этих "заводов-производителей запорной арматуры" через дефис... Боюсь сделать ошибку. И к тому же, имеет ли значение, что после приложения идет название заводов?

...эксклюзивный представитель крупнейших мировых заводов — производителей запорной арматуры (...) на территории Российской Федерации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае при любой пунктуации (думаю, в исходном тексте нужно тире и не нужна запятая) останется неясным, это "представитель в России" или "представитель заводов на её территории". Поэтому я бы преобразовал уточнение в причастный оборот, это за счёт запятой позволит исключить второй вариант понимания:

... представитель крупнейших мировых заводов, производящих запорную арматуру, на территории Российской Федерации.

Можно попытаться и перенести "территорию":

... эксклюзивный для территории Российской Федерации представитель крупнейших мировых заводов — производителей запорной арматуры.

("Эксклюзивный" - понятие относительное и условное, здесь может быть смысл "работающий исключительно с российскими партнёрами на особых для них условиях", "единственный, имеющий в России лицензию" и т.п. подразумеваемые исключительные качества)

Comment: Представитель крупнейших мировых заводов на территории Российской Федерации.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь правильно ставить тире, и не надо смотреть, что там пишут в интернете.